# Java get the number of seconds between 2 dates

Tags: java, time, calendar

I'm trting to send data every 10 seconds , 
so I'm trying tp use this code I wrote 
but I think I made a mistake in the converting to seconds?

```
Calendar Time= Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar SendDate= Calendar.getInstance();

long upload = TimeBetweenDates(SendTime,Time);

if (upload > 10000) {
    String udp = "OK";
    SendUDP(udp);
    SendTime = Calendar.getInstance();
}


public static long TimeBetweenDates (Calendar Start , Calendar End) {
    long end = End.getTimeInMillis();
    long start = Start.getTimeInMillis();

    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Math.abs(end - start)); 
}
```

Comment: What dates are you putting in? What number did you get? What number did you expect?

Comment: Why aren't you just use a `ScheduledExecutor` for sending so you don't have to calculate a difference at all?

Comment: Your `TimeBetweenDates` method seems like it should be correct except that in Java method and variable names begin with a lowercase letter. I find it confusing that you have parameters `Start` and `End` and variables `start` and `end`. In what way does your observed behaviour differ from the desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're "trying to send data every 10 seconds", you can just do

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool();

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> sendUdp("OK"), 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: this is not good for my beacue I need to make an IF with the send .      if time is more then 10 or the data is not the same  - the send.

Comment: @Korenron I did mean for you to adjust the submitted task, you can easily add the check you want.